# Tag Top users Math

Tags: support, reputation, top-users

On stackoverflow, the top user of the [c# tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers) (who is also the top user overall) has a total score > 121k.

I thought this meant 121k upvotes on answers, which would mean 1 210 000 reputation points.

This seems false since Jon Skeet has *only* 678k reputation (unless he had a huge number of downvotes, which we can doubt).

How come? **Has the reputation system changed the way it attributes points?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a daily reputation cap; you can earn at most 200 points per day for votes.

20 upvotes on answers gets you to 200 points, after that it's only bonuses and accepts that earn you more reputation.

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Makes it even more impressive to get this much reputation. Do you guys ever sleep? :)

Comment: Soundly! It just takes time. Jon's close-to-30k answers weren't written overnight. :-)

Comment: I get that, but with a 200 points limit, in 5y3months, it means a maximum of about 408k... Meaning Jon Skeet probably got the 200 points every day :O

Comment: @GôTô: It means he gets bonuses and answer accepts too.

Comment: @GôTô: I average about 350 points per day, for example. That's 200 from upvotes, the rest is mostly accepts and the occasional bonus.

Comment: Yes, it's just impressive to get this many accepted answers+points on a daily basis. I'm happy when I get 3 :)